# Unix Bash rename files using a regex

Tags: bash, rename, mv

I would like to rename all files from a folder using a regex(add a name to the end of name) and move to another folder.

It my opinion, it should be looking like this:

`mv -v ./images/*.png ./test/*test.png`, but it is not working.

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also like the rename command that John T posted, but it's not available on all systems.  This should work everywhere:

```
for i in *.png; do mv -v $i `basename $i .png`.test.png; done
```

Comment: here's what it returns:

usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory

Comment: Worked for me: perhaps you should try quoting instances of your $i:  "$i"

Comment: It works also for mac.

Comment: This is, more or less, the standard UNIX way of doing the task, as all you need is a Bourne shell. The perl method is newfangled. Cool, but new-fangled.

Comment: @EricJLN: it's only "new-fangled" compared to UNIX itself -- Perl's been around for more than two decades now. (by comparison, the Bourne shell's only a single decade older; `bash` is the same age as Perl.) the Perl Cookbook was published in 1998 and includes a simple version of the same script; it's certainly older than that.

Answer (score 7):

There's a handy perl file-renaming script that gets installed with the main Perl package on Debian-based systems (including Ubuntu).  It's usually named `rename`, but sometimes is called `prename` (Perl rename).  Use like this:

```
rename expr file1 file2 file3
```

The command uses Perl to evaluate `expr` for each `file` argument, and it renames each file to the output of the `expr` evalutation.  So, for simple regex replacements like your example:

```
rename 's(images/(.*)\.png$)(test/$1.test.png)' ./images/*

# here's the expression:
# s()()   -- just like s/// (but i don't need to escape the / in the filename)
#   match regex:  images/(.*)\.png$     -- match filenames of the form images/*.png
#   replace:      test/$1.test.png     -- turn them into test/*.test.png
```

If files don't match the expression (for example, non-PNG files), the substitution won't do anything and their filenames won't be changed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rename` which accepts regular expressions or this basic 3 argument syntax:

```
rename .png .test.png *.png
```

- The first argument is what to replace in the filename
- The second argument is what to replace it with
- The third argument is what files to perform the operation on, in this case, all pngs.

Comment: is this the same as the perl rename i describe, or something else?  i'm not familiar with the syntax you describe.

Comment: I don't think so. This one is a binary. See here: http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename and here:  http://pastebin.ca/1726871 .

Comment: thx, that's interesting.  might be why the rename i mentioned gets installed to `/usr/bin/prename` and then symlinked to `/usr/bin/rename`.